# JavaScript userinput URL without holding my domain

Tags: javascript, html, url, web

I'm having a little trouble with JavaScript. My problem is that I have a user input box (where a user would enter a URL) - and a button (when clicked, it will open the URL that the user has typed in the input box).

Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" id="userurlbox"/>
<button type="button" onClick="myFunction()">Open URL</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x = document.getElementById('userurlbox').value;
if (x == "")
{
alert('Please enter a URL');
}

else
{
window.open(x ,'_blank');
}
</script>
```

The problem is that the URL opens like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/USERURL
```

I want it to open like this:

```
http://USERURL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code only adds the 'http://' if it is not already included:

```
function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById('userurlbox').value; 
        if (x == "") {
            alert('Please enter a URL');
        }
        else {
            if (x.substr(0,4).toLowerCase() === 'http') { // only test first 4 characters as we want to allow both http:// and https://
                window.open(x ,'_blank');
            }
            else {
                window.open('http://'+x);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested, you need to include the  `'http://'` in the window.open

```
<input type="text" id="userurlbox"/>
<button type="button" onClick="myFunction()">Open URL</button>

<script>
function myFunction(){
var x = document.getElementById('userurlbox').value;

    x = x.replace('http://'.''); // remove  http:// just in-case it is there

    if (x == "")
    {
        alert('Please enter a URL');
    }    
     else
    {
       window.open('http://' + x ,'_blank');
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! But what if the user already adds http:// to the url input box, how would I fix that haha?

Comment: I have just updated my post - nice and simple solution and easy to read

Comment: Note that not all urls will be http, some might be https. To auto-detect such behavior, omit the protocol entirely. Simply prepend the sanitized url with //.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you can override the relative/absolute url behavior just using the window.open function, so a viable solution would be to check if the url begins with https?:// and prepend '//' if it does not. A url starting with // will always be treated as absolute.